# Alternative of window.status

Tags: javascript, html

Window.status is not working.

I know it is deprecated already, however I want to know the alternative of that.

Below is the exact code of mine.

My code is like below which is available in separate .js file.

```js
window.status=“ok”;
location.href=“Jspfilename.jsp”
```

I have code in Jspfilename.jsp like below,

```js
if(window.status == “ok”) // getting window status as null value instead of ok
{
…
}
```

getting `window.status` as null value instead of ok.

I need to get `window.status="ok"`

Answer (score 2):

`window.status` was deprecated because it was harmful to the user experience, not because a better way of achieving the same effect came along.

The alternative to it is displaying content *in the document itself*.

---

That said, your code *appears* to be using it as some arbitrary global variable instead of for any of its intended purposes, so you could just use a real global variable instead (or a more neatly scoped variable depending on how your code is arranged).

A second look suggests you might be trying to use it to pass data between pages, in which case look at using Local Storage (for persistent data) or just encoding it in a query string on the URL (for ephemeral data).